# Why does CorePlot 0.2.2 build fine for the Simulator, but give a link error for the device?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-plot

Core Plot works fine when building for the Simulator. However, it gives a link error when I try to build for the device:

[image: deleteTest - deleteTest.xcodeproj]

What could cause this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for this issue is to check the Build Active Architecture Only setting for your App and Core-plot.

This wasn't pointed out in the Instructions for Core-Plot and was overlooked by me. Hope it helps someone else.

[image: deleteTest - deleteTest.xcodeproj]